# GitHub GraphQL: Get all forks of a repository

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, git-fork

I would like to get a **list of all the forks** (with timestamp) of a specific repository.
When I try the following on [explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

```
{
  repository(name: "tensorflow", owner: "tensorflow") {
    forkCount
    forks(first: 100) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

It returns the forkCount correctly and as displayed on the [webpage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), but unexplainably there are **over 15,000 fewer repositories in the "forks" list** as displayed on the webpage and forkCount. Consequently, I am missing the timestamp for these repositories.

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "forkCount": 86841,
      "forks": {
        "totalCount": 70082
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this? How do you get the other repositories?

The visibility of a fork repository cannot be changed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forks.totalCount` shows the number of direct forks of this repository. `forkCount` also includes forks of forks and this number may be bigger

Credit for the answer goes here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/33375#discussioncomment-3671593